# Access Postgres CTE values from trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, sql-delete, database-trigger

How can I access `var` value from delete trigger for `objects` table, or maybe there is another way to pass variable from sql query to trigger function?

```
with var as (select <val>) delete from objects where id=<num>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you think you need to access those values? Isn't the information _which_ row was delete (and all its column values) enough?

Comment: Trigger writes some fields of modifyed or deleted record to a separate table and i want to add a user id of whom performs this operation. I can get user id for update request because i can read it from new.updater_uid field, but for delete request new refers to null.

Comment: Then use `old.updater_uid`

Comment: `old.updater_uid` contains uid of whom updated record previously but not of whom is trying to delete it now.

Comment: Are you looking for `current_user` then?

Comment: `current_user` gives me postgresql user, not my 'program logic' user. I'm developing GIS server with jsrpc client api and postgresql as data storage, clients can create and delete objects, so i need to track history of objects. Of course i can `insert into objects_history (..., updater_uid) value (...,<uid>); delete from objects where ...` but cause of heavy load i want to reduce costs with DB triggers on UPDATE and DELETE events.

Comment: Are you using postgres user to connect to your database or is that delete query executed by some function with security definer and owner set to postgres? If latter, then `session_user` should show name of role executing said function.